# Extract a substring from xml column from SQL query resultset

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table `MYTABLE` and column `MYXML` in **Oracle 12 database**. The column `MYXML` contains strings like below with varied lengths -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:NodeData xmlns:ns2="http://abcd.org/xyz/schema/">
    <Head msgId="ACVF63980FGQW56123" orgId="12345" ts="2017-04-13T18:37:27+05:30" ver="1.0"/>
    <Info>
        <Identity id="45298" verifiedName="MFROMLA" type="TECH"/>
        <Rating name="HIGH"/>
    </Info>
    <Node Name="PQ" Desc="PreQualified" NodeID="2387ajdh231dqhhg21098"/>
</ns2:NodeData>
```

I want to extract just `PQ` from this column values using SQL query. How do I do that? I should be able to search using `Name` tag if possible and extracts its value.

Comment: Where is the example of String?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?that really help

Comment: I have given xml string above. Lets say "select MYXML from MYTABLE" gives you that string. How to extract PQ from that string in the same query as another column?

Comment: How do I extract from above xml?

Answer (score 1):

This is one query you could use, it extract attribute `Name` of node `Node` from your xml string. Assume that `MYXML` datatype is `VARCHAR2`

```
SELECT EXTRACT(xmltype(myxml), '/Node/@Name') 
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: I am getting errors when using column name directly in xmltype. do we have to convert it to xml? Datatype is varchar. ORA-19032: Expected XML tag , got no content
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at line 1
19032. 00000 -  "Expected XML tag %s got %s"
*Cause:    When converting XML to object, a wrong tag name was present
*Action:   Pass a valid canonical XML that can map to the given object type

Comment: How to get data from new xml I posted above?

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a `varchar2`, you can use string methods; for example, these are two ways with and without regular expressions:

```
SELECT substr(myXml, 13, instr(myXml, '"', 1, 2) - 13),
       regexp_substr(myXml, '"([^"]+)"', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
FROM mytable
```

If your column is `XMLTYPE`, you can use the XML approach:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(myXml, '/Node/@Name')
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
select name from mytable, xmltable(xmlnamespaces ('http://abcd.org/xyz/schema/' as "ns2"),'ns2:NodeData/Node' passing xmltype(myxml) columns name   varchar2(50) path '@Name');
```